# Can azurerm_key_vault_certificate set a password on a certificate when generating a new one?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

I ran into an issue generating self-signed certificates via the Azure Key Vault where it wasn't possible to add a Subject Alternate Name at the time of creation.

To work around that I tried to create the keys via the `azurerm` terraform provider. The keys generate successfully but don't have a password.

From what I can see on the documentation for `azurerm_key_vault_certificate` [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault_certificate#secret_properties) a password value can only be added in a `certificate` block, which is only used when *importing* a certificate.

I feel a bit stuck between not being able to create a certificate with a SAN via the portal and not being able to create a certificate with an encryption password via terraform. Am I missing something?

Comment: in the documentation link you shared, the password field is to extract the .pfx file which is password protected before the certificate is imported to the keyvault. just to get an idea, why do you need to do put an encryption password via terraform when you're storing it in the keyvault?

Comment: I may have misunderstood something so please do correct me. My understanding was that its still best practice to have a password on the certificate because it can be extracted and distributed in pfx form to other destinations. You can set a password when you generate a certificate through the portal (but cant set a SAN).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can azurerm_key_vault_certificate set a password on a certificate when generating a new one?

While generating a certificate in azure key vault, you cannot set password.
In terraform, to create a new certificate, you have to use *certificate_policy* argument in *azurerm_key_vault_certificate* resource which doesn't have password parameter and setting password is only support for importing certificate.

> I ran into an issue generating self-signed certificates via the Azure Key Vault where it wasn't possible to add a Subject Alternate Name at the time of creation.

I used the following Terraform code to generate a certificate with a Subject Alternative Name in Azure Key Vault:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "kvcert01" {
  name         = "kvcertvjy"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.kvkisdujfgweuvjy.id

  certificate_policy {
    issuer_parameters {
      name = "Self"       # for self-signed certificates
    }

    key_properties {
      exportable = true
      key_size   = 2048
      key_type   = "RSA"
      reuse_key  = true
    }

    lifetime_action {
      action {
        action_type = "AutoRenew"
      }

      trigger {
        days_before_expiry = 30
      }
    }

    secret_properties {
      content_type = "application/x-pkcs12"
    }

    x509_certificate_properties {
      # Server Authentication = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
      # Client Authentication = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2
      extended_key_usage = ["1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"]

      key_usage = [
        "cRLSign",
        "dataEncipherment",
        "digitalSignature",
        "keyAgreement",
        "keyCertSign",
        "keyEncipherment",
      ]

      subject_alternative_names {
        dns_names = ["portal.contoso.com", "terraform.hello.world"]
      }

      subject            = "CN=hello-world-terraform"
      validity_in_months = 12
    }
  }
}
```

Terrafrom Output: https://i.imgur.com/P0ZO9Cw.png
Verify in portal:
[image]

> I feel a bit stuck between not being able to create a certificate with a SAN via the portal and not being able to create a certificate with an encryption password via terraform. Am I missing something?

You can create a certificate with SAN in portal by setting DNS names by following the below steps.
[image]

Verify the certificate
[image]

Comment: I realised the "DNS Names" section added the SAN only yesterday after posting this question. The lack of any reference to SAN on the page or in the azure docs really threw me.

Your answer matches all of the conclusions I reached after asking the question and investigating further so I'm marking it as correct. Thanks for the effort.